# Превратить в объект с элементами

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть код, надо переписать его в объект чтобы потом по нему пробегать циклом и вызывать selectItem.Какой он должен иметь вид

```js
$(function() {
  $(".letters").click(function() {
    $('.code-pick').addClass("block");
  });
  $('.code').click(function() {
    $('.code-select').addClass("block");
  });
  $('.month').click(function() {
    $('.apply-none').addClass("block");
  })
  $('.long-code').click(function() {
    $('.month-pick').addClass("block");
  });
});

function selectItem(el) { //rename
  el.addClass('block');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const baz = el => {
  el.classList.add('block');
}

[...document.querySelectorAll('[data-widget="foo"]')].forEach(node => {
  baz(node);
});
```

```css
.block {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="code" data-widget="foo">1</div>
<div class="letter" data-widget="foo">2</div>
<div class="work" data-widget="foo">3</div>
```